# ArangoDB manual cluster setup inside a VPC

Tags: arangodb

How can i setup a scalable arangodb cluster with google compute instances running ubuntu? I tried using "arangod" and "arangodb", but i keep getting the errormsg "Flaky agency communication to http+tcp://10.34.10.4:5002. Unsuccessful consecutive tries".

Comment: This can be safely ignored. We get this from time to time in GKE, but never impacted anything.

Answer (score 0):

`Flaky Agency communication` means that the communication of the agency (the inner parts of the arangodb cluster) is sometimes to slow.

The agency is implementing [RAFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raft_(computer_science)) which demands proper timing between the agents.

The agents should live on the same local network, their communication roundtrips should be quick.